# Dagger 1 and Dagger 2 package names conflict

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, dagger, dagger-2

I have an Android project in which one 3rd party library depends on `Dagger 1` and my project on `Dagger 2`.

Dagger 1 and 2 have the same package names so my app is working fine, but 3rd party library is not working because of overriding dagger 1 package by dagger 2.

Changing the package name of Dagger 2 to `dagger2` instead of `dagger` is not an option because annotation compiler is generating classes with static package name `dagger`.

Is there a way of resolving this conflict?

Comment: Hello, Could you add more description about which library is depending on Daggar 1 and generating annotations?

Comment: 3rd party library is depending on dagger 1 and my app is depending on dagger 2 which is using dagger 2 compiler

Comment: Are you able to say which library that is?

Comment: You mean that 3rd party library? Its companies internal private library. The main problem is how to use dagger 1 and dagger 2 in one android project without conflicts?

Comment: Rework your project to use dagger 1.

Comment: This is obvious option but not the solution of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use jarjar on the 3rd party library jar, or at least the dagger parts. That will move the dagger code (and any references) into its own package. As that is happening after the annotation processor has run it should catch all the code.

Comment: I tried that but dagger 2 generated DI factories with old dagger 2 package name - I think dagger 2 annotation processor has dependencies on original dagger 2 sources for generation classes.
I didnt find any way how to solve this so I used Dagger 1 instead. :(

Comment: @DConan - I'm a little confused. If the dagger 1 code has been repackaged to something else how can that affect dagger 2? Does dagger 2 process the repackaged files in some way?