# Supporting a Dagger 2 dependency in a Dagger 1 project

Tags: android, gradle, google-play-services, dagger-2

This is a follow-up to [my question about Play Services Cast Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60148919/large-number-of-remoteserviceexceptions-in-googles-cast-medianotificationservic), where the solution seems to be updating from v17.0.0 to v18.0.0. The new version unfortunately has a dependency on Dagger 2, whilst the (large & complex) project is Dagger 1.

We are currently using:

```
api "com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:17.0.0"
api "com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework:17.0.0"
```

Updating these to 18.0.0 results in:

```
> 1 exception was raised by workers:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class dagger.Lazy found in modules dagger-1.2.2.jar (com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.2.2) and dagger-2.22.jar (com.google.dagger:dagger:2.22)
Duplicate class dagger.MembersInjector found in modules dagger-1.2.2.jar (com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.2.2) and dagger-2.22.jar (com.google.dagger:dagger:2.22)
Duplicate class dagger.Module found in modules dagger-1.2.2.jar (com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.2.2) and dagger-2.22.jar (com.google.dagger:dagger:2.22)
Duplicate class dagger.Provides found in modules dagger-1.2.2.jar (com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.2.2) and dagger-2.22.jar (com.google.dagger:dagger:2.22)
```

Ideally I'd be able to let the new version of the library use Dagger 2 whilst the rest of the app uses Dagger 1. Reworking the project to use Dagger 2 is a multi-week undertaking.

Any ideas?

---

### What I've tried already:

Excluding Dagger 2 from the cast framework via:

```
api("com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:18.0.0") {
    exclude group:'com.google.dagger', module:'dagger'
}
api("com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework:18.0.0") {
    exclude group:'com.google.dagger', module:'dagger'
}
```

unsurprisingly resulted in:

```
   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ldagger/internal/Preconditions;
        at com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.DaggerTransportRuntimeComponent$Builder.setApplicationContext(com.google.android.datatransport:transport-runtime@@2.1.0:150)
```

---

Forcing the cast framework to use an older version via the following also resulted in duplicate classes:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        preferProjectModules()
        dependencySubstitution {
            substitute(module("com.google.dagger:dagger:2.22")).with(module("com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.2.2"))
        }
    }
}
```

---

Potentially related questions that didn't help:

- [Dagger 2 application using library that uses dagger 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38334891/dagger-2-application-using-library-that-uses-dagger-1) - No answers / comments.
- [Dagger 1 and Dagger 2 package names conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32452209/dagger-1-and-dagger-2-package-names-conflict) - Seems to be a different issue further down the line.
- [How do I make Dagger 1 and Dagger 2 coexist together in one Android project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53292197/how-do-i-make-dagger-1-and-dagger-2-coexist-together-in-one-android-project) To do with migration, not resolving dependency in third party library.

Comment: I am also facing the same problem. Any solutions you found?

Comment: Nope. We gave up and spent a few weeks migrating to Dagger 2.

Comment: Thank you. If nothing is possible then we also have to do the same. Is it possible to make it work without migrating it to Dagger 2? Any thoughts?

Comment: I have no idea I'm afraid, if we had any ideas we would have tried it! Sorry.